# OpenCV frame inconsistent with numpy slicing

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I’m trying to print the detected blob on a black NumPy array frame which is same size of ordinal frame i.e (640, 1280)

operating system
    Ubuntu
architecture (e.g. x86)
    x64
opencv4.1.0-python version 3.6.8

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('1.mp4')

e1_x1 = 760
e1_y1 = 150
e1_x2 = 845
e1_y2 = 195

e2_x1 = 800
e2_y1 = 150
e2_x2 = 880
e2_y2 = 200


black = np.zeros((640, 1280, 3), dtype = "uint8")
def blobSelection(eye,black):
    keypoints=blob_detector.detect(eye)
    for ma in keypoints:
        print(x,y)
        black = cv2.drawMarker(black, tuple(int(i) for i in ma.pt), color=(0, 255, 0))
    return black

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    e1 = frame[e1_y1:e1_y2, e1_x1:e1_x2]
    cv2.rectangle(black, (e1_x1,e1_y1), (e1_x2,e1_y2), (255,0,0), 1, 8, 0)

    cv2.rectangle(frame, (e1_x1,e1_y1), (e1_x2,e1_y2), (255,0,0), 1, 8, 0)
    cv2.putText(frame, "e1", (e1_x1, e1_y2), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.rectangle(black, (e2_x1,e2_y1), (e2_x2,e2_y2), (255,0,0), 1, 8, 0)

    cv2.rectangle(frame, (e2_x1,e2_y1), (e2_x2,e2_y2), (255,0,0), 1, 8, 0)
    cv2.putText(frame, "e2", (e2_x1, e2_y2), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    e2 = frame[e2_y1:e2_y2, e2_x1:e2_x2]

    e1 = eyeDetection(e1, black)
    e2 = eyeDetection(e2,black)

    cv2.imshow('Orginal', frame)
    cv2.imshow('Detected eye', black)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]
I want the two eyes from the man in the source image pasted onto the black background at same.

Comment: And what errors are you getting with what you have already?

Comment: I suppose the green detection is done in e1 and e2 right? those are cropped portions of the image. The resulting points are relative to this frame. So you would have to add e1_y1 and e1_x1 to the results of e1 for example. And you do the same with e2

Comment: yes, something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that this

```
e1 = eyeDetection(e1, black)
```

will actually call this

```
def blobSelection(eye,black):
```

You would need to pass the offset to draw it in the correct place, since you do the detection to eye which is part of frame, and the resulting keypoints can be drawn inside eye and not black.

```
keypoints=blob_detector.detect(eye)
```

My suggestion will be to do something like this:

```
def blobSelection(eye,black, offset):
    keypoints=blob_detector.detect(eye)
    for ma in keypoints:
        pos = ma.pt
        black = cv2.drawMarker(black, (ma.pt[0] + offset[0], ma.pt[1] + offset[1]), color=(0, 255, 0))
    return black
```

And you call it like:

```
e1 = blobSelection(e1, black, (e1_x1, e1_y1))
```

Assuming that (e1_x1, e1_y1) is the top left corner of e1